# A smooth path through the set of all positive definite matrices

Tags: general-topology, inner-products, positive-definite

Let $\mathfrak S(n)$ be the set of all positive definite $n\times n$ (real) matrices. I am no expert in topology but stumbled across this question: Does there exist a smooth path through $\mathfrak S(n)$?

I know already that $\mathfrak S(n)$ can be made to a topological space by equipping the set with the topology inherited from the canonical inner product for $n\times n$ matrices $A$, $\Vert A\Vert = \sqrt{\mathrm{trace}(A'A)}$. But what are the requirements for a smooth path to exist?

Comment: You mean, like a space filling curve?

Comment: The set of positive definite matrices is convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $A, B \in {\mathfrak S}_n$, $(1-t) A + t B$, $0 \le t \le 1$, is a smooth path in ${\mathfrak S}_n$ from $A$ to $B$.